# mysql current timestamp on updating data

Tags: mysqli

I would like to have the current timestamp if updating the column of an mysql table. Try the following configuration:

Name: LAST_UPDATE

Typ: TIMESTAMP

Attribute: on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Null: NOT NULL

Standard: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Extra: ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Unfortunately it only change the timestamp if I made a change through phpMySQL but not on a normal SQL Update command through php. I don't want to change all my sql-queries;-)

what is wrong?

thanks

Comment: please show the whole DDL of your table : In PHPmyadmin, export the structure of the table to get that

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

Only set this fields.

```
Name: LAST_UPDATE
Type: TIMESTAMP
Default: As defined '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
Attributes: on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Use this query "ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME>
CHANGE `LAST_UPDATE` `LAST_UPDATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP "

Answer (score 0):

The whole DDL of the Table looks like that

```
CREATE TABLE `xp_tags` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`SID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ART` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
```

...

```
`LAST_UPDATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```